# How to redirect form submit to original form

Tags: php, html, forms

Ok, I have a form which sits inside of a popup box. I want the confirmation message to display inside of the pop up box when the form has been successfully submitted.

How do I do this?

I have the site live that I am working on, take a look here [www.firestarmediallc.com](http://www.firestarmediallc.com)

When you get to the site, click the GET QUOTE link on the top of the page and the box will appear.

Actually, if you guys could take a look at the mailer functions and see if those are correct too, that would be awesome. I have been trying to get this form functional for the last two days and haven't had any luck.

Sorry, I just realized that you can't see the php file. Thank you in advance. Here it is:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "tabethamoe@yahoo.com";
$email_subject = "Quote Request";


function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['phone']) ||
    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}

$first_name = $_POST['name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['phone']; // not required
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = "^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$";
if(!eregi($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
$string_exp = "^[a-z .'-]+$";
if(!eregi($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}

if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($phone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

$('#contactform').submit(function () {
    sendContactForm();
    return false;
});

<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The site's not loading, but if you want a form to submit to itself, you simply have:

```
[... deleted irrelevant code, now that I can see how the site works...]
```

Comment: What browser are you using, because it loads fine for me. This might be an issue for me. :(

Comment: Must've been a network glitch, working fine now. it was hanging on the initial connection attempt.

Comment: Your popup is an in-document type thing, I figured you meant an actual popup window created with `window.open()` or whatever. To get the form submission to work within the confines of that popup, you'd have to do the form submission via AJAX.

Comment: You know of any good sites that can walk me through that? I have no experience with AJAX.

Comment: There's not much different between ajax and regular form submission, other than it's being done in the background by javascript, and the server-side scripts tend to return JSON data instead of html. You're already using jquery on the site, and that'll handle a huge chunk of the ajax side of things for you.